# Node.js HTML5 Boilerplate Server Config Integration

Tags: node.js, express, html5boilerplate

I'm setting up the structure of a new project which will be built using Node.js and Express. I 'm using [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for an optimal starting point. It comes with configuration files for multiple types of servers: Apache, Nginx, Node.js, etc. The following is the [Node.js server configuration file](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs) provided by the HTML5 Boilerplate team:

```
/* h5bp server-configs project
 *
 * maintainer: @xonecas
 * contributors: @niftylettuce
 *
 * NOTES:
 * compression: use the compress middleware provided by connect 2.x to enable gzip/deflate compression
 *                          http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/compress.html
 *
 * concatenation: use on of the following middlewares to enable automatic concatenation of static assets
 *                              - https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager
 *                              - https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/connect-assets
 */
var h5bp    = module.exports,
   _http    = require('http'),
   _parse   = require('url').parse;

// send the IE=Edge and chrome=1 headers for IE browsers
// on html/htm requests.
h5bp.ieEdgeChromeFrameHeader = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      var url = req.url,
         ua = req.headers['user-agent'];

      if (ua && ua.indexOf('MSIE') > -1 && /html?($|\?|#)/.test(url)) {
         res.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=Edge,chrome=1');
      }
      next();
   };
};

// block access to hidden files and directories.
h5bp.protectDotfiles = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      var error;
      if (/(^|\/)\./.test(req.url)) {
         error = new Error(_http.STATUS_CODES[405]); // 405, not allowed
         error.status = 405;
      }
      next(error);
   };
};

// block access to backup and source files
h5bp.blockBackupFiles = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      var error;
      if (/\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~/.test(req.url)) {
         error = new Error(_http.STATUS_CODES[405]); // 405, not allowed
         error.status = 405;
      }
      next(error);
   };
};

// Do we want to advertise what kind of server we're running?
h5bp.removePoweredBy = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      res.removeHeader('X-Powered-By');
      next();
   };
};

// Enable CORS cross domain rules, more info at http://enble-cors.org/
h5bp.crossDomainRules = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
      next();
   };
};

// Suppress or force 'www' in the urls
// @param suppress = boolean
h5bp.suppressWww = function (suppress) {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      var url = req.url;
      if (suppress && /^www\./.test(url)) {
         res.statusCode = 302;
         res.setHeader('Location', url.replace(/^www\./,''));
      }
      if (!suppress && !/^www\./.test(url)) {
         res.statusCode = 302;
         res.setHeader('Location', "www."+url);
      }
      next();
   };
};

// Far expire headers
// use this when not using connect.static for your own expires/etag control
h5bp.expireHeaders = function (maxAge) {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age='+ (maxAge));
      next();
   };
};

// Etag removal
// only use this is you are setting far expires for your files
// ** WARNING ** connect.static overrides this.
h5bp.removeEtag = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      res.removeHeader('Last-Modified');
      res.removeHeader('ETag');
      next();
   };
};

// set proper content type
// @param mime = reference to the mime module (https://github.com/bentomas/node-mime)
h5bp.setContentType = function (mime) {
   return function (req, res, next) {
      // I'm handling the dependency by having it passed as an argument
      // we depend on the mime module to determine proper content types
      // connect also has the same dependency for the static provider
      // ** @TODO ** maybe connect/express expose this module somehow?
      var path = _parse(req.url).pathname,
         type  = mime.lookup(path);
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', type);
      next();
   };
};

// return a express/connect server with the default middlewares.
// @param serverConstructor = express/connect server instance
// @param options = {
//    root: 'path/to/public/files',
//    maxAge: integer, time in miliseconds ex: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 30 days,
//    mime: reference to the mime module ex: require('mime')
// }
// Depends:
//    express or connect server
//    mime module [optional]

h5bp.server = function (serverConstructor, options) {
   var server = serverConstructor.createServer(),
       stack = [
         this.suppressWww(true),
         this.protectDotfiles(),
         this.blockBackupFiles(),
         this.crossDomainRules(),
         this.ieEdgeChromeFrameHeader()
      //,this.expireHeaders(options.maxAge),
      // this.removeEtag(),
      // this.setContentType(require('mime'))
       ];
   // express/connect
   if (server.use) {
      stack.unshift(serverConstructor.logger('dev'));
      stack.push(
         //serverConstructor.compress(), // express doesn't seem to expose this middleware
         serverConstructor['static'](options.root, { maxAge: options.maxAge }), // static is a reserved
         serverConstructor.favicon(options.root, { maxAge: options.maxAge }),
         serverConstructor.errorHandler({
            stack: true,
            message: true,
            dump: true
         })
      );
      for (var i = 0, len = stack.length; i < len; ++i) server.use(stack[i]);
   } else {
      server.on('request', function (req, res) {
         var newStack = stack,
             func;
         (function next (err) {
            if (err) {
               throw err;
               return;
            } else {
               func = newStack.shift();
               if (func) func(req, res, next);
               return;
            }
         })();
      });
   }
   return server;
};
```

My question is this: how exactly do I go about integrating this with Express? The section of code that specifically confuses me is the bottom portion:

```
// return a express/connect server with the default middlewares.
// @param serverConstructor = express/connect server instance
// @param options = {
//    root: 'path/to/public/files',
//    maxAge: integer, time in miliseconds ex: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 = 30 days,
//    mime: reference to the mime module ex: require('mime')
// }
// Depends:
//    express or connect server
//    mime module [optional]

h5bp.server = function (serverConstructor, options) {
   var server = serverConstructor.createServer(),
       stack = [
         this.suppressWww(true),
         this.protectDotfiles(),
         this.blockBackupFiles(),
         this.crossDomainRules(),
         this.ieEdgeChromeFrameHeader()
      //,this.expireHeaders(options.maxAge),
      // this.removeEtag(),
      // this.setContentType(require('mime'))
       ];
   // express/connect
   if (server.use) {
      stack.unshift(serverConstructor.logger('dev'));
      stack.push(
         //serverConstructor.compress(), // express doesn't seem to expose this middleware
         serverConstructor['static'](options.root, { maxAge: options.maxAge }), // static is a reserved
         serverConstructor.favicon(options.root, { maxAge: options.maxAge }),
         serverConstructor.errorHandler({
            stack: true,
            message: true,
            dump: true
         })
      );
      for (var i = 0, len = stack.length; i < len; ++i) server.use(stack[i]);
   } else {
      server.on('request', function (req, res) {
         var newStack = stack,
             func;
         (function next (err) {
            if (err) {
               throw err;
               return;
            } else {
               func = newStack.shift();
               if (func) func(req, res, next);
               return;
            }
         })();
      });
   }
   return server;
};
```

My JavaScript isn't exactly at a beginners level but I wouldn't say I'm advanced either. This code is beyond me. Any pointers as to what I can read, watch, or do, to learn what I'm obviously missing here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Most of the file](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/502a454/node/node.js#L18-123) is made up of a series of functions that generate middleware for frameworks, like Express, that conform to Connect's middleware specification. The second code listing is designed to create an HTTP server that *uses* all these functions. From what I can tell, it looks like you're supposed to pass in whatever you would normally call `createServer` on, and h5bp will do the creation and setup for you. For example, if you would normally do:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express.createServer();
```

You would instead pass `express` to `h5bp.server`, which calls `createServer` on whatever you pass in right off the bat:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = h5bp.server(express, options);
```

After a bit of setup, it checks to see if the server has a function called `use` (the line is `if (server.use)`), and if so uses it to inject all the middleware it set up into the server. If it *doesn't*, then it assumes you're using a raw Node.js HTTP server, and sets up the necessary code to pass the request through each of the items in `stack` manually (this is what Connect/Express does for you).

It's worth noting that, in Express 3 (currently in release candidate stage), the applications created by Express no longer inherit from Node's HTTP server, so you don't call `createServer` on `express`; instead, you should just call `express()` and then pass the results of that into `http.createServer`. (See "Application function" at [Migrating from 2.x to 3.x on the Express wiki](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) for more information.) This means that this script is not compatible with the latest version of Express.

[update]

If you take a look at the `test` directory on GitHub, you can see [an example app](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/blob/master/test/node-server.js):

```
var express = require('express'),
   h5bp     = require('../node.js'),
   server   = h5bp.server(express, { 
      root: __dirname,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 30
   });

server.listen(8080);
console.log('ok');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's quite informative. Since, as you said, the provided script isn't compatible with Express 3, I guess I'll merely try to replicate the functionality myself. Again, thanks for the concise, informative, and quick response.

Comment: Glad to have helped. You'll probably find, while looking through the script, that each of the middleware are pretty self contained and self explanatory, and not that hard to implement. (As a matter of fact, I realized I forgot to redirect `www.` traffic on a recent project and used a modification of their technique to implement it.)

Answer (score 1):

There was a major update of **h5bp** for node.js.
You can use it as an **express** middleware now.

The repository has moved here : https://github.com/h5bp/node-server-config.

From the documentation:

```
var express = require('express'),
h5bp = require('h5bp');

var app = express();
// ...
app.use(h5bp({ root: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// ...
app.listen(3000);
```